# Responsive widths, not heights, in threejs

Tags: three.js, responsive

I have noticed that in threejs, every example of the sizing of an object relative to its container seems to only be based on the height of the canvas/window it is responding to. This works well for worlds where the canvas is the only thing on the page. However, in a new project we are using overlaying divs as part of the design and as the window gets thinner, we are hoping to be able to scale down the main object in our scene. I have linked to and took 2 screenshots of a basic example. I am wondering if anyone has come up with a good solution for dealing with making the width responsive as well.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube

[image: wide image]

[image]

Comment: The way you describe the problem is sort of odd ... maybe you're misunderstanding what's happening in those examples. The object in the scene isn't being resized, but rather the aspectRatio of the camera-frustum is being adjusted according to the pixel-aspect-ratio of the window/screen/renderer. Knowing that, short of dynamically adjusting the scale of the object/scene according to the shape of the window, you might try dynamically adjusting the camera.fov accordingly. As a very rough/crude test, you can try something like camera.fov = Math.max( 70 / camera.aspect, 70 );

Comment: Math.max( 70 / camera.aspect, 100 ) rather ... would produce better results.

Comment: Cool. I will check this out. I'm used to doing responsive CSS based on window width and kinda new at thinking in webgl terms, but thanks for giving me a starting point on this